# Android iframe white screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is very confusing to solve, I'm using Capacitor.

I have a simple iframe that loads a website on a page when the user clicks a button.

```
<iframe src="https://subdomain.domain.com" width="200px" height="200px"></iframe>
```

On my android version 6. The iframe loads fine on development mode (using ionic capacitor run android -l --external) and also by installing it from Google Play.

On my android version 10. The iframe loads fine on development mode (using ionic capacitor run android -l --external) BUT **not working** by installing it from Google Play. It shows a white screen with a frame border around the page. Meaning no content.

Also on the browser, the iframe loads fine.

Does anyone know what might cause this and a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iframe not working in Ionic app on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018489/iframe-not-working-in-ionic-app-on-android)

Comment: no it doesn't help

Comment: Its probably a security issue. Securities keep changing with OS versions. So maybe take a look here https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/allowlist/index.html if something can help you out in your configs.

Comment: which security issue might that be? can you help. that allowlist from cordova already included as default in capacitor https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config

Answer (score 0):

This is weird maybe someone can provide an explanation.
I ended up fixing this by placing another iframe with width & height = 0;

```
<iframe src="https://sub-domain.example.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.example.com" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```